# Copy animation to other Object

Tags: animation

New to animation here.
I'm trying to copy the animation I made for the C and paste it onto the 3 other letters and then have them play one shortly after the other. I used Ctrl+L > Animation data which causes the K to move to the C and they play at the same time.
Is there a way to copy the C animation over to the other letters allowing me to edit the delay on the other letters?
Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select the animated object and copy `strg+c` all the key frames in the Dope sheet editor
2. Set key frame on all channels were you want to paste on your target object. otherwise, you cant paste there.
3. Paste `strg+v` your key frames on the target object
4. Since you pasted the location of object on your objects are now inside each other. You most likeley want to tweak the animations in the graph editor.

[image]

Comment: It worked! All I needed to do was add a key frame. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to copy animation from one object to multiple objects.

1. Select the objects that you want to give the animation and also select the object from which you want to copy the animation. Make sure that the already animated object is selected last so that it is the active object.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>L</kbd> and choose *Animation Data* this will link the animation data of one object to another but after this, making changes in the original object's animation will also affect the linked object's animation.
3. To solve this, select the linked object(s) go to *Object > Relations >  Make Single User > Object Animation Data*. This will make the linked object a single user.